# How to drawstring on an image in other than english language (java)

Tags: java, graphics

I want to draw some text on an image in punjabi language usin java drawstring method. Please help me to understand, what i am doing wrong?

```
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
     Graphics g = image.createGraphics();
     g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
     g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(),image.getHeight());
     g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
     String data="ਸਾਨੂੰ ਵੇਖ ਕੇ ਮੁਖ ਘੁਮਾ ਜਾਂਦੇ ,ਸਾਡੇ ਨਾਮ ਤੇ ਨੀਵੀਆਂ ਪਾ ਜਾਂਦੇ , ..ਪਰ ਇਕ ਗੱਲ ਤੇ ਨਾ ਚੱਲਦਾ ਜ਼ੋਰ ਉਹਨਾਂ ਦਾਕਰਦੇ ਗੱਲਾਂ ਗੈਰਾਂ ਨਾਲਤੇ ਕਸਮਾਂ ਸਾਡੇ ਨਾਂ ਦੀਆਂ ਖਾ ਜਾਂਦੇ...";

     try {
        Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("/var/gurbaniwebthick.ttf"));
        font = font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN,20);
        GraphicsEnvironment ge =
                GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            ge.registerFont(font);
            g.setFont(font);
    } catch (FontFormatException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
     g.drawString(data,10, 20);
     try { 
       ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("/var/javatest/1.jpg"));
     } catch (IOException e) { 
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Comment: The above could works! Have you saved your java file in utf-8? Have you tested to just remove the font you've referenced. Could be that the font is not utf-8.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Problem has been fixed when i used the unicode punjabi font.